# I can't recover firebase error in redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I created my store with Redux-Toolkit and my slice. Now I want to retrieve the data using firebase. I created an async thunk using `createAsyncThunk`. I want to register a user using email and password. The registration is ok, but when I want to register the same user again, it doesn't capture and display an error message.

```js
export const signUp  = createAsyncThunk('signUp', async (user) => {
  const {email, password} = user
   
  const response = await fetch('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=<KEY VALUE REDACTED>', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password })
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    console.log("nous")
    throw new Error("Nous avons un problème lors de l'inscription")
  }
    
  const data = response.json()
  return data 
})
```

```js
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  if (email.length > 0 && password.length > 0) {
    if (isSignUp) {
      setError(null)

      try {
        dispatch(signUp({ email, password }))
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    } else {
      // alert('Veuillez remplir tous les champs')
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just catch error from fetch i.e. change code from

```html
const response = await fetch('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyBzVe7Kti-H852fIzBemumnCYbMODXCIH8', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password
    })
});
```

to this

```html
  const response = await fetch('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyBzVe7Kti-H852fIzBemumnCYbMODXCIH8', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email:"test@gmail1.com",
      password:"2345dxfcghj"
    })
  }).catch(err=>err)
```

Answer (score 0):

`createAsyncThunk` actions always resolve, so there's a little bit of a refactor you can do to your code to make working with errors better.

- Surround the asynchronous logic in a `try/catch`.
- Wait for the `response.json()` Promise to resolve.
- Return a rejection with value. See [Handling Thunk Errors](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-errors).
- Wait for, and unwrap, the asynchronous action in the UI code. See [Handling Thunk Results](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-results).

```js
export const signUp = createAsyncThunk(
  'signUp',
  async (user, thunkApi) => {
    const { email, password } = user;

    try {
      const response = await fetch('....', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password })
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        console.log("nous");
        throw new Error("Nous avons un problème lors de l'inscription");
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      return data;
    } catch(error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

```js
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  if (!email.length || !password.length || !isSignUp) {
    // alert('Veuillez remplir tous les champs')
  }

  setError(null);

  try {
    const data = await dispatch(signUp({ email, password })).unwrap();
    // Signup was successful
  } catch (error) {
    // Signup failed, handle error
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```